# GEE: how to return pixels at edges detected by ee.Kernel.laplacian8

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, edge-detection

I wanted to detect edges in an image and return an image containing all pixels adjuscent to the edges (pixels from the original image).

I used this published code:(from https://developers.google.com/)

```
// Load and display an image.
var image = ee.Image('LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_TOA/LC08_044034_20140318');
Map.setCenter(-121.9785, 37.8694, 11);
Map.addLayer(image, {bands: ['B5', 'B4', 'B3'], max: 0.5}, 'input image');
// Define a Laplacian, or edge-detection kernel.
var laplacian = ee.Kernel.laplacian8({ normalize: false });

// Apply the edge-detection kernel.
var edgy = image.convolve(laplacian);
Map.addLayer(edgy,
             {bands: ['B5', 'B4', 'B3'], max: 0.5, format: 'png'},
             'edges');
// Set a threshold for edge detection
var edgeThreshold = 0; 

// Create a binary mask based on the edge threshold
var edgeMask = edgy.gt(edgeThreshold);

//Display the edge mask on the map
Map.addLayer(edgeMask, {palette: '000000,FFFFFF', opacity: 0.5}, 'Edge Mask');
```

Then I have tried to get the pixels of the image at the edge using focamax() and then multiply the result with the original image. However, the focalmax return an image with extremely high resolution (different from landsat image resolution).

```
// Create a buffer zone around the edges
var bufferZone = edgeMask.focalMax(30, 'square', 'meters');

var bufferPixel=image.multiply(bufferZone);
// Display the buffer zone on the map
Map.addLayer(bufferPixel, {palette: '00FF00', opacity: 0.5}, 'Buffer Zone');
```

Is there a way to return the original pixels (from landsat image) at the edges, instead of the buffer zone?